# Check if a variable is a date with Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have an array of variables that I want to display in a Twig template and each variable can be either a string or a date.

If the variable is a date, I want to apply the `date` filter like this:

```
{{ my_var|date('d/m/Y') }}
```

And if it's a string I want it to display it the usual way:

```
{{ my_var }}
```

Is there any way to test if a variable is a date (ie. an instance of the PHP DateTime object)?

Comment: related issue on github: [Consider an instanceof test](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/553)

Comment: @DanLee Thanks, that's interesting but I understand why the PR has been closed without being merged as this would look like a kind of mix between PHP and Twig.

Comment: Yes indeed, it's not really the business of the view. Thought  it may help if you really wanted to implement the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788138/instanceof-operator-in-twig-symfony-2/27038954#27038954 where a test has been added in order to check the type of the variable.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Maybe not the best way to do it, but I found a solution to my problem.

```
{% if my_var.timestamp is defined %}
    {{ my_var|date('m/d/Y') }}
{% else %}
    {{ my_var }}
{% endif %}
```

As a `DateTime` PHP object has a public `getTimestamp` method, it's a way to check if the variable is a date whether this property is set or not.

Comment: +1 I'd say thats a perfectly fine way to do it, you'd need some sort of conditional statement somewhere unless you wanted to create a twig extension

Comment: You could try to call `date()` like: `date(my_var) ? my_var|date('d/m/Y') : my_var`.

Comment: The 'is defined' part is called a [Test](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#test-operator) in Twig. Perhaps you could [add your own](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#tests) called `a_date`, and do something like `{% if my_var is a_date %} ...`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I dont think that'd work, I think you'll get an error. This should work ok though: `{{ my_var.timestamp is defined ? my_var|date : my_var }}`

Comment: @Prisoner yep just ran some tests and it doesn't work...the `timestamp` is definitely a solution!

Comment: **Beware:** twig `date` filter (kind of) gracefully degrades, rather than failing. It didn't fail for any of these input (´'2'´, ´'0'´, ´true´, ´false´, ´''´, ´' '´, ´not_exist´) but it gave unexpected results instead.

Answer (score 7):

Michael's solution works in most cases, but there are some special cases you should consider when you want to have a universal solution.

First, an object that you test for having a `getTimestamp()` method doesn't have to be a `DateTime` instance. I can thing of many cases when the timestamp field would be useful in an object, so I would test the `getTimezone()` method instead.

Second, if `my_var` is an object having a magic `__call` method defined, then all such tests would turn out positive. That's why I suggest the following negative test:

```
{% if my_var.timezone is defined and my_var.nonExistingProperty is not defined %}
    {{ my_var|date('m/d/Y') }}
{% else %}
    {{ my_var }}
{% endif %}
```

The second case was the one I recently struggled with because of using Propel ORM objects. The base class has the `__call` method that catches all Twig `is defined` tests.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a `class(my_var)` function, for example:

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/HelperExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_SimpleFunction;

class HelperExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('class', array($this, 'getClassName')),
        );
    }

    public function getClassName($object)
    {
        if (!is_object($object)) {
            return null;
        }
        return get_class($object);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
{% if class(my_var) == 'DateTime' %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
{% if myDate is instanceof('\DateTime') %}
```