# How to use new TWIG Extension

Tags: symfony, twig, extension-methods

I'm facing a trouble with how to use a new created twig Extension in the twig template, but unless I get it works, I don't understand why

Lets explain wit the example

```
class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension 
{

    public function getTests(){
        return array('instanceof' =>  new \Twig_Test_Method($this, 'isInstanceof'),
                     'appenmantenimiento' => new \Twig_Test_Method($this, 'appEnMantenimiento')
                    );
    }


    public function isInstanceof($var, $clase) {
        $class = "AppBundle\\Entity\\".$clase;
        return  $var instanceof $class;
    }

    public function appEnMantenimiento(){
        check the DataBase....
        return TRUE or FALSE;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return "mytwig_extension";
    }

}
```

So, how can I use the appEnMantenimiento function, I mean

```
{% if entity is instanceof('MyClass') %} {# WORKS FINE #}
{% if appenmantenimiento() %} OK {% endif %} {# DOESN'T WORK #}
{% if true is appenmantenimiento() %} OK {% endif %} {# WORKS fine with the returned value form appenmantenimiento() #}
```

But the problem is that I don't understand why

Comment: You are mixing `tests` with `functions`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#id2)

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788138/instanceof-operator-in-twig-symfony-2

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add getFunctions method? 
For more details please see: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#id2

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('instanceof', array($this, 'isInstanceof')),
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('appenmantenimiento', array($this, 'appEnMantenimiento'))
    );
}
```